# Prestashop and https

Tags: https, prestashop

I have problem with https. In console I have

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://home.pl/pl/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://home.pl/img/cms/home.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: You don't have a problem with https, you have a problem with mixing content. Simply load everything over https, job done.

Answer (score 1):

The console "shows" the solution. You should serve the home.png with https, so the correct url should be `https://home.pl/img/cms/home.png`

In the .tpl use this snippet to check if is active the SSL mode in backoffice.

For example.

For the link:

```
<a href="http{if Tools::usingSecureMode()}s{/if}://mylink.com">My link</a>
```

For images:

```
<image src="http{if Tools::usingSecureMode()}s{/if}://home.pl/img/cms/home.png">
```